# Javascript key based values push into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code

Example in PHP

```
$a = [];
$a['test1'][] = 1; 
$a['test1'][] = 2;
```

Output: `Array ( [test1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )`

How to do in javascript same thing?.

Comment: you can use `.push()`

Comment: a['test1'].push(1); tried but getting error.

Comment: `var a = {}; a.test1 = []; a.test1.push(1);`

Comment: You have to init `test1` as array first

Comment: yes. It's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Javascript` you can create an object with key `test1` and assign an array as the `value`. Then you can use [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to insert multiple elements on a single call:

```js
let a = {};
a['test1'] = []; 
a['test1'].push(1, 2);
console.log(a.test1)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or alternatively, you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
let a = new Map();
a.set('test1', []);
a.get('test1').push(1, 2);
console.log(a.get("test1"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code.

```
var a = {}; 
a.test1 = []; 
a.test1.push(1);
```

Result: `{test1: Array(1)}`

Answer (score 0):

Just make an object:

```js
var a = {};
a["test1"] = 1;
a["test2"] = 2;
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you want an array, you would have to use numeric indexes instead of names:

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
console.log(a);
```